# Performance constraints of non pro version of viewflow

Tags: django-viewflow

I'm looking towards using viewflow to design a workflow app for my company.  I would like to know about performance constraints of using the non-pro version of viewflow.  Besides this I'd like know if using the unpayed version I can change the default front-end that comes with viewflow and if so in which direction should I start looking to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm, there is no pro/non pro performance specific constraints in the viewflow. Viewflow PRO adds additional functionality to the open source version.

Fo the customization options you could check the viewflow cookbook - https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook (custom views and custom UI samples)

Comment: Oh thanks! All I want to modify is adding a menu item that links to a another page in the default bar that is left of the interface. Doing so I've seen the cookbook and the examples design the frontend basically from scratch or at least that is what I understand. Could you explain to me how could I do this? 

Beside this my company is interested in getting the pro version, is there a "trial version" that I could  show them?. Also on that topic I was wondering if  the viewflow pro single package comes with the materials-front end package.